# Issue writing Calculated Column Formula

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I've looked at this formula over and over again, but the system will not except it when I attempt to create a Calculated Column.

Does anyone see any problems with it?

```
=IF( [Approve/Reject-1]="Rejected"
     , "Rejected"
     , IF( [Special Exceptions]!="None"
           , "Approved"
           , IF( [Approve/Reject -2]="Approved" 
                 ,"Approved"
                 , "Rejected"
               )
         )
    )
```

Comment: Hint: https://www.deskbright.com/excel/does-not-equal-in-excel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `NOT` is not represented by `!=`, but instead by `<>`.  Try it like this:

```
=IF([Approve/Reject-1]="Rejected","Rejected",IF([Special Exceptions]<>"None","Approved",IF([Approve/Reject -2]="Approved" ,"Approved","Rejected")))
```

Comment: I didn't mean to steal the answer from Danny.  If he posts an answer, please unaccept mine and accept his instead.